# Find the port bound by snap-server

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

Using snap-server's `httpServe` method, I can `setPort 0` to instruct the server to connect on the next free port. Unfortunately, once I have started the http server, I can't find any way to determine which port it actually started on. As an example, my first try started on port 2679 - is there any way to determine that number?

Comment: To my knowledge we don't currently have a way to do this.  The problem with Don's suggestion of using the Config structure is that `httpServe` checks command-line parameters and might modify the config after it is passed in.  It's not clear to me how this problem should be solved.  Did you have a particular API in mind?

Comment: No API in mind, just a use case :) One option would be for the Snap monad to return it as some kind of parameter/global-state? Or pass the port in? Note that even if the command-line doesn't change the port, it's still wrong if you pass 0 as the port.

Comment: Does your use case suggest something about the API?  For instance, if you want to know the port so you can send a request from code, then it does no good to have a Snap monad action that returns the port.

Comment: I'm evil enough to ``unsafePerformIO`` and ``IORef`` anywhere I can get the value :) My use case is when a request comes in, spawn a new server on a fresh port, and then redirect to there. The spawned server has to communicate the port back to a different process. An ideal API would be: ``setPortCallback :: (Int -> IO ()) ->  Config m a -> Config m a``, where that function is called with the port.

Comment: As a slight generalisation, ``setSocketCallback :: (Socket -> IO ()) -> Config m a -> Config m a`` would give me enough information, and perhaps be useful for others as well.

Comment: In any case, it would be nice to have some kind of callback once the server is "awake", even for other purposes - so you could feasibly call this ``setInitCallback``

Comment: Hmmm, how about just decoupling the command line argument processing and exposing a new httpServe variant that uses exactly the config passed in?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11655/discussion-between-mightybyte-and-neil-mitchell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote [this patch](https://github.com/snapframework/snap-server/pull/24), included with `snap-server` 0.9 and above, using which you can write:

```
let hook dat = print $ socketPort $ head $ getStartupSockets dat
let config = setStartupHook hook $ setPort 0 mempty
httpServer config ...
```

Now `hook` will be called after the server is ready, and will print the port it started on.

Comment: Is there any way to find the port from within a handler or snapletinit? I have your need, as well as needing to know the port at later points as well (for specifying callbacks in response to requests).

Answer (score 0):

The Config structure has [a bunch of getters](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap-server/0.6.0.1/doc/html/Snap-Http-Server-Config.html#v%3agetPort), no?

```
getPort :: Config m a -> Maybe Int
```

Returns the port to listen on (for http)

Comment: getPort tells you what you set the port to be, not what port it actually used - in my case it returns 0. In contrast to what @mightybyte said, even if there is no command line modification, this would still be incorrect as port 0 gets auto-resolved to something else.